# dynamic stack allocation on the device with cuda

Tags: cuda, c++14

Title says it all.

Is there anything similar to alloca() functionality in cuda but for the device side? I need to allocate small-sized arrays(nxn and nx1, with n<=10), n is a dynamic variable.

thanks!

Comment: No.  you can use `malloc` or `new` in-kernel.  However you should usually take care to free such allocations.

Comment: what about writing asm directly?

Comment: To my knowledge, the closest feature to mimic that behavior is shared memory. Depending on the type and your kernel you may also want to try a statically allocated array that may endup in registers.

Comment: If sizes are as small as listed then just allocate the maximum dimension on the stack (uint32_t buffer[10*10]) or allocate out of shared memory. A small fixed size allocation is likely to be supported in registers with no local memory spills/fills. A dynamic allocation such as alloca would result in local memory access to device memory. In this case shared memory would have lower latency.

Comment: regarding a small max sized buffer, the problem is that these allocations are done inside of eigen, math lib. i wanted to know if i can make a patch generic enough or i have to somehow get around this for my problem.

Comment: As with Cuda 11, there is a `__host__ __device__ alloca` function.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to use `malloc` or `new` inside the kernel. Be careful though, as this will allocate memory in the global memory space.